# 'RNNRootViewProtocol.h' file not found when build ios

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

does anyone know how to fix this issue when building ios:
'RNNRootViewProtocol.h' file not found
[image]

React Native version: 0.59
React-native-navigation version: 2.26.5